# DotNetNuke Beginner's Tutorial

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I have just installed the latest version of Dot Net Nuke.I am new to this CMS.Can anybody help to start with it.

Comment: Have you tried google or some other search engine?

Comment: i have tried ,But it seems to be some problem here.Portal is working fine but i am unable to edit any page via portal.

Comment: In that case you should probably edit your question to reflect the problem you are having.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you start by looking at the Tutorials page on DotNetNuke.com http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Training/Tutorials.aspx specifically check out the **Getting started with DotNetNuke 6.2 Series** though you are probably using DNN7 the videos will for the most part still apply.

disclosure: Most of those videos are ones I created while employed at DNNcorp, even though I not longer work there, they are still extremely useful.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer isn't near as valid anymore as DNNCorp has jacked their entire site and lost a lot of content, including those tutorials I had originally mentioned. They might still be there, but I can't find them easily.

Comment: Agreed. As of the date I write this, the DNN software website is horrid. The so-called tutorials page is especially bad. I can't tell whether there is anything useful on that page or not. Have posted to the DNN software "Beginner's" forum a comment on what I am looking for as a beginner, and how awful that page is. We'll see if my post makes it through their "moderation". I like .Net technologies, but if this website is indicative of the direction DNN is going, I hesitate to make use of it. May switch to a PHP-based CMS.

Comment: FYI, the initial learning experience with DNN was so ..dubious.., that even though my career has been primarily .NET, I am spending the next few days attempting to build a website with Drupal. Of the top PHP+MySQL based CMS's, it seems most like what I am accustomed to as a Microsoft .Net programmer.  DNN doesn't seem to have the resources and polish behind it.